# Is it risky to use freed memory

Tags: c, memory-management

Suppose I have a char pointer which points to some string in memory.
and suppose I want to copy that string to some other place in memory.

```
void cpy(char **dst, char *src)
{
    *dst = (char *) realloc(*dst, strlen(src) + 1);
    memcpy(*dst, src, strlen(src) + 1);
}
```

(Assume memory allocation is successful, and `src` is not NULL)
What if I call this function like this:

```
char *str = malloc(14);
memcpy(str,"hello, world!", 14);
cpy(&str,str+7);
```

Now I would expect `srt` to point to the string `"world!"` (Which it does in my tests).
But what concerns me is that in this call to `cpy`, `*dst` and `src` actually point to different locations of the **same** string. And, when calling `realloc` on `*dst`, it's possible that this memory will be freed. But in the next line I'm trying to copy from that place with `memcpy`.

So the questions is: Is there something wrong with it?
Or to put it another way - is it okay to free memory, and use it immediately afterwards?

Thanks.

**Note:** The example was updated so that `realloc` is called on memory that was obtained with `malloc`.

Comment: If you're still doing things to the memory, you are not done with it. So don't call `free` until you are done with it.

Comment: Thank you, @kerrekSB, your update answers my original intention in the question. If you don't mind, I'd be glad to know **why** it's not allowed to access memory in such a way (that was freed just in the previous line, and has no yet had the chance to be altered by anything else).

Comment: How can you guarantee it hasn't been altered by something else. In a multi threaded program, freed memory could have been reallocated in another thread. The main point though is this, accessing memory that you have "freed" or said "I am done with that" is undefined behavior and thus should be avoided.

Comment: @EyalAr: It's just not allowed. The C standard is a list of things you *are* allowed to do, not a list of things that are forbidden -- the latter wouldn't be possible! The only thing you *are* allowed after `realloc` is access the *new* memory. The system may well have returned the old memory to the OS, or done other things with it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Everything is wrong with this. It is outright *undefined behaviour* to call `realloc` on a pointer that was not obtained with `malloc` etc.

As @Daniel Fischer points out, it is also undefined behaviour to use `memcpy` on overlapping regions of memory (in which case you should use `memmove`), so you have to be careful.

---

**Update:** After your substantial edit, the question is quite different. It is now equivalent to this condensed version:

```
char * s = malloc(14);
strcpy(s, "hello, world!");

char * p = realloc(s, 14);

memcpy(p, s, 14);
```

This is also undefined behaviour, because you are not allowed to access the memory pointed to by `s` anymore after a successful `realloc`, and you're not allowed to access the memory pointed to by `p` after an unsuccessful `realloc`.

Comment: Also, calling `memcpy` with overlapping memory blocks is UB.

Comment: +42 - Simply for the comment "Everything is wrong with this". I wish I could upvote this a bunch of times.

Comment: ok, good point, but that's not the point of the question. let's say i'm calling `realloc` on a memory that was obtained with `malloc`. what then?

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thanks for that, I've included that in the post!

Comment: @EyalAr Then when your function is called as `cpy(&str,str+7);`, `src` is indeterminate when it is passed to `memcpy()`.

Comment: @EyalAr: Then you have a completely different question.

Comment: @PascalCuoq `cpy(&str,str+7);` It's quite possible that `realloc` doesn't move the memory. Okay, after counting, the blocks don't overlap, the one stops right where the other begins.

Comment: @EyalAr - calling `realloc` on memory obtained by `malloc` is fine, but you aren't allowed to assume that the memory block was just expanded in-place. You must assume that it is no longer in the same location and adjust your pointers accordingly.

Comment: @DanielFischer I deleted that comment because it is stupid to assume that `realloc()` does nothing (property on which my count was predicated). The program invokes undefined behavior when `src` is passed to `memcpy()`.

Answer (score 1):

The implicit assumption in your example is that it is permitted for `cpy` to free memory it didn't allocate. It's kind of a dodgy assumption, but as long it's intentional, that's OK. Use `malloc` and `free` separately rather than `realloc` in that case:

```
void cpy(char **dst, char *src)
{
    // obtain completely new memory (realloc might do this anyway)
    char* new = malloc(strlen(src) + 1);

    // duplicate the string
    memcpy(new, src, strlen(src) + 1);

    // release the original memory now that we know we are done with it
    free(*dst);

    // indicate where to find the new string
    *dst = new;
}
```

This still isn't a great idea, because there's no way to know what other variables might be pointing at that memory that you're `free`ing, but if you have a way to make that guarantee, this is the kind of code you need.